# How to replace a string in a list of strings in a DataFrame (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe which consists of lists of lists in two seperate columns.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame()
data["Website"] = [["google.com", "amazon.com"], ["google.com"], ["aol.com", "no website"]]
data["App"] = [["Ok Google", "Alexa"], ["Ok Google"], ["AOL App", "Generic Device"]]
```

[Thats how the Dataframe looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZa7G.png)

I need to replace certain strings in the first column (here: "no website") with the according string in the second column (here: "Generic Device"). The replacing string has the same index in the list as the string that needs to be replaced.

**What did not work so far:**
I tried several forms of *str.replace(x,y)* for lists and DataFrames and nothing worked. A simple *replace(x,y)* does not work as I need to replace several different strings. I think I can't get my head around the indexing thing.
I already googled and stackoverflowed for two hours and haven't found a solution yet.

Many thanks in advance! Sorry for bad engrish or noob mistakes, I am still learning.

-Max

Comment: hey Max, are you able to show your intended output?

Comment: @all: Thank you very much! All your codes worked on my sample data, but not when I integrate it into my own script. I have to find out why, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Happy Holidays!

I wasn't really sure what your expected output was and I'm not really sure what you have tried previously, but I think that this may work:

```
data["Website"] = data["Website"].replace("no website", "Generic Device")
```

I really hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try this,You can define replaceable values in a array and execute.

```
def f(x,items):
    for rep in items:
        if rep in list(x.Website):
            x.Website[list(x.Website).index(rep)]=list(x.App)[list(x.Website).index(rep)]    
    return x

items = ["no website"]
data = data.apply(lambda x: f(x,items),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                     Website                        App
0   [google.com, amazon.com]         [Ok Google, Alexa]
1               [google.com]                [Ok Google]
2  [aol.com, Generic Device]  [AOL App, Generic Device]
```

Answer (score 2):

Define replacement function and use apply to vectorize

```
def replacements(websites, apps):
    " Substitute items in list replace_items that's found in websites "
    replace_items = ["no website", ] # can add to this list of keys 
                                     # that trigger replacement

    for i, k in enumerate(websites):
        # Check each item in website for replacement
        if k in replace_items:
            # This is an item to be replaced
            websites[i] = apps[i]  # replace with corresponding item in apps

    return websites

# Create Dataframe
websites = [["google.com", "amazon.com"], ["google.com"], ["aol.com", "no website"]]
app = [["Ok Google", "Alexa"], ["Ok Google"], ["AOL App", "Generic Device"]]
data = list(zip(websites, app))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Websites', 'App'])

# Perform replacement
df['Websites'] = df.apply(lambda row: replacements(row['Websites'], row['App']), axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                   Websites                        App
0   [google.com, amazon.com]         [Ok Google, Alexa]
1               [google.com]                [Ok Google]
2  [aol.com, Generic Device]  [AOL App, Generic Device]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function like this:

```
def f(replaced_value, col1, col2):
    def r(s):
        while replaced_value in s[col1]:
            s[col1][s[col1].index(replaced_value)] = s[col2][s[col1].index(replaced_value)]
        return s
    return r
```

and use `apply`:

```
df=df.apply(f("no website","Website","App"), axis=1)
print(df)
```